# Execute exe from asp.net that is published under wwwroot

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem to execute a application under wwwroot.
It works fine when i run before published my site but it doesn't work as soon as my site is under wwwroot.

Here my codes

```
AppDomain sendBox = AppDomain.CreateDomain("sandBox");
string fileName = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Rangoon\\Reports\\ReceiptPrinter.exe";
sendBox.ExecuteAssembly(fileName);
AppDomain.Unload(sendBox);
```

Note: I set IIS permission for my site folder.
Please help thank you all.

Comment: You can have look at ProcessInfo Class for your requirement

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: There's no error sir.I set `MessageBox.Show("HI")` at `FormLoad()` but it not comes out.This means my site can't call the  application.

Comment: I changed the above code like this.Also not works

`System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();`
`process.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/ReceiptPrinter.exe");`
`process.Start();`
`process.WaitForExit();`

Comment: Could you make it work in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the executable (ReceiptPrinter.exe) is a .NET assembly. No native .exe will work there.

Comment: Sir it works if i double click this application manually.Calling from my site just not works.Is there anything i can do?